# Creating array of List storing class object?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

May i ask if the following code i wrote is correct? Basically, i want to create an 2D array, and within each array, i want to have a list of vertices. So if tCount and pCount is 10, i would have 100 different lists storing vertices. The adding of the vertices will be done elsewhere after certain operations are done to determine which list the vertice should be added to.

```
List<Vertice>[,] lists = new List<Vertice>[tCount, pCount];
for (int i = 0; i < tCount; i++) {
    for (int o = 0; o < pCount; o++) {
        lists[i,o] = new List<Vertice>(); } }
```

Pardon me for posting such a simple question, because i have posted a similar qns in another forum and the replies i received kind of confused me. But thanks for reading!

Comment: what happened when you ran and tested it?

Comment: `var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, tCount)
                          .Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat(new List<Vertice>(), pCount).ToArray())
                          .ToArray();`

Comment: Just as an aside...consider using j instead of o as your inner loop variable...o is a terrible choice in most IDE's

Comment: Why not a List<List<Vertice>> ?

Answer (score 0):

Mitch Wheat- There was no error so far, but i am also not sure if the list is created properly..

Damith- I've seen that before but i do not really understand the code, so i was wondering if the code i typed was correct or not. I feel safer using a code that i understand, although i do understand the benefits of using a 1-liner.

Oberdan Nunes- I need it to be in a 2D array, as it is related to another 2D array of data which i have.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. When you want to reply to comments you should use the `add comment` link underneath the comments, and post a comment. This answer section is just for answers.